# dynamic memory allocation- why there is no "delete" at the end of the program?

Tags: c++

I have 2 questions regarding to the program below:
1. Does the program create only the elements(type rectangle and hexagon) as dynamic, or also the pointers to them are dynamic?

2.why the program doesn't have a delete at the end. for example something like this:(if I assume correctly that only the elements are dynamic..)

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    delete shapeArray[i];
```

Thank you very much,this website helps me a lot with things that my teachers can't help!
Shiran

the program is:

```
 int main()
{
 // Create array of pointers to Shapes of various types.
 const int NUM_SHAPES = 3;

 Shape * shapeArray[] = { new Hexagon(),
 new Rectangle(),
 new Hexagon()
 };

 // Set positions of all the shapes.
 int posX = 5, posY = 15;
 for (int k = 0; k < NUM_SHAPES; k++)
     {
 shapeArray[k]->setPosition(posX, posY);
 posX += 10;
 posY += 10;
};

 // Draw all the shapes at their positions.
 for (int j = 0; j < NUM_SHAPES; j++)
{
 shapeArray[j]->draw();
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Your program creates an array of pointers to Shape on the stack. The array size is known at compile time from the length of the initializer list {}. Each element in the initializer list is the address of a Shape created on the heap through operator new.
2. The fact that they are not freed is bad style, your OS will release the dynamic memory allocated when a program exits so it won't have some consequences in this particular case, but leaving memory not deleted make the detection of "true" memory leaks more difficult.

Comment: +1 for example of not only bad style, but unfortunate consequences

Comment: Since explicit deletion on shutdown of all dynamically-allocated objects is difficult, dangerous and unjustified with a complex, busy multithreaded app that is running on multiple cores, why bother with explicit deletion in simpler apps?  Only the OS has the tools to easily stop all running threads before deallocating memory - it should be left to do the job.  How can a style that eliminates complex shutdown code and removes deadlocks and AV/segfaults be described as 'bad'?

Comment: It becomes complicated to detect memory leaks in a program if there are a lot of memory not getting deallocated by the program itself, a leak detector will report those as memory leaks, making the report unreadable. If there are particular reasons making that deallocation complicated, I guess it's OK to let the OS do that.

Comment: This is at best confusing. The **pointers are created on the stack.** The objects they point to, by contrast, are created on the heap, via new() for each shape.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes. It allocates memory only for the pointers. It creates an array of 3 pointers with the following:

```
Shape * shapeArray[] = { new Hexagon(),
 new Rectangle(),
 new Hexagon()
 };
```

2) On program exit, the memory allocated for the pointers will be usually recalimed by the operating system. However, you should `delete` them explicitly so as to not rely on what OS does and you may loose  track and run into memory leaks as the program grows in size.

Comment: 1)if it allocates the pointers(*shape type)..so at which stage did it allocate the elements(shape type)?..

Comment: @Shiran when you call `new` for those objects, it's done at runtime.

Comment: How can you say that it allocates memory only for the pointers? It clearly allocates memory for the shapes as well, via new. **Both** allocations happen at run time, since neither has static storage class. The array resides on the stack and holds three pointers which are being initialized with addresses of three shapes on the heap.

Comment: I edited the answer because I found it really misleading/wrong. Some of the comments, including my own, may consequently seem out of place.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I see (1) being misleading but I corrected in my comment though. Btw, I don't see any edit..may be, ypu commented on the wrong answer?

Answer (score -1):

All memory occupied by your program will be freed after exit by OS so there is no reason to delete it here.

Comment: Depends. On most modern OSs, yes. Of course, that's not a *good* reason to get lazy.

Comment: Not completely, for an example if you call this program from another process in windows several times I think it will leak.

Comment: @Esteban, no, that should not happen.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: depends what Estaban means by "call this program". If the other process opens this executable as a dll, looks up the "main" function and calls it several times then you'd have a leak. The standard doesn't allow for that, but some OSes do. Also, any code that's *currently* in a `main` function might be useful in future if moved to a function that *is* intended to be linked and called. And it'll be more useful if it doesn't leak memory.

Comment: @SteveJessop OK, so you may have found a corner-case where you can persuade some code, called in some way, on some OS, to leak.  The poster stated 'no reason to delete it here', and there is not.  I have to upvote.

Comment: @MartinJames: if you like. I don't think that odd situation is what contradicts "no reason to delete it" -- I think it's the spurious reports from leak-checking tools that are the main reason to delete it. My comment was in response to what Esteban and Amigable were saying about "calling this from another process", which is ambiguous. It might mean "executing a a child of another process, to run this program", in which case it doesn't leak. It could mean literally calling it, in which case of course it does leak.

Comment: There are even a few situations where I would advocate letting the OS do the cleanup. In a sufficiently large app that uses a lot of memory, most of which gets paged out, shutting down the app can be a very expensive operation simply because all the memory needs to be paged back in just to recursively free everything. The OS would drop the whole lot without needing to page it in. So as a rare optimization it might be nice for some apps to leak (and with great care to ensure that no objects whose destructors do anything substantial are included in the leak).

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Oh my. Thanks. I deleted my comment since I don't want plain wrong statements in the wild, even if immediately corrected.